Make omits '-I' flag g++
I have a makefile to make a project with 2 source files and one header.
.PHONY: clean delete run                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

CC = g++                                                                                                                                          

CFLAGS = -g -Wall                                                                                   

CXXFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

SRC = /home/hk_grub/dev/nCPrograms/Flagger/src/theclass.cpp /home/hk_grub/dev/nCPrograms/Flagger/src/main.cpp                                     

OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

INC = -I/home/user/dev/nCPrograms/Flagger/header                                                                                                                              

EXECUTABLE = Flagger                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

all: $(EXECUTABLE)  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJ)  
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o $@ $^

%%.o: %%.cpp                                                                                                                                              
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

clean:                                                                                                                                                    
  rm -rf $(OBJ)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

delete:                                                                                                                                                   
  rm -rf $(OBJ) $(EXECUTABLE)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

run:                                                                                                                                                      
  ./$(EXECUTABLE)   

When I run it with make, it outputs this command that it is running (without the -I flag):
g++ -g -Wall   -c -o /home/user/dev/nCPrograms/Flagger/src/theclass.o /home/user/dev/nCPrograms/Flagger/src/theclass.cpp

and then fails with an error because one of the includes relies on a -I flag.
/home/user/dev/nCPrograms/Flagger/src/theclass.cpp:1:10: fatal error: theclass.h: No such file or directory                                        1 | #include <theclass.h>                                                                                                                           |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                     compilation terminated.                                                                                                                           make: *** [<builtin>: /home/user/dev/nCPrograms/Flagger/src/theclass.o] Error 1  

I have tried @echo'ing the $(INC) variable (worked fine), and moving around parameters and adding/removing quotations everywhere. I'm not super familiar with make syntax, so any help as to why the -I flag is not appearing would be appreciated. For what it's worth, the include path and #include directive work fine with clangd and when manually compiling.

Why did you write %%.o: %%.cpp?

Is the content quoted above in the question REALLY your makefile?  It seems quite bizarre.  Just as the most obvious example, in the second-to-last line you delete $(EXECUTABLE) then in the last line you run ./$(EXECUTABLE)...!!!  Maybe you mis-pasted your makefile here?  I don't want to write an answer based on a bogus example.

@MadScientist. Scroll all the way right. The delete and run lines apparently (should?) belong to delete and run targets respectively but I can't fathom the formatting.

Oh, I see.  For the OP, before submitting your question to StackOverflow please use the preview feature to verify it looks correct, especially the examples.  If you forget to do that please check AFTER you post your question and edit it to be correct.

Sorry, '\n' was not preserved from windows terminal to clipboard to StackOverflow

It seems you are using GNU Make.
This:
%%.o: %%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

is not a pattern-rule.
It is a rule for making a file literally called %%.o from a file literally called %%.cpp.
This rule has no application and is not used.
Instead, make falls back on its built-in rule
to compile an .o from a .cpp file, which is:
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c

Your variable INC is not used in that recipe (it is not one of the make-variables used by implicit rules)
so your -I path is not passed. It would be conventional to pass -I-paths in CPPFLAGS (preprocessor flags).
The pattern rule you need is:
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

